# Finding the diameter of a tree using double DFS in C++

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search

I'm attempting a problem on SPOJ where I'm supposed to find the longest path between any two nodes in a tree. The input consists of the number of testcases t, the number of nodes n, followed by n-1 edges given by "a b l", with a referring to node 1, b referring to node 2, and l referring to the length of the edge. I tried using the double dfs method, performing dfs on node 1 first to find the longest possible path beginning from node 1. Afterwards, I perform dfs on the node furthest away from node 1, finding the longest possible distance. Unfortunately, my code is wrong and I'm not sure why at all, and i'm hoping someone could help me out. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I did manage to solve the problem using double BFS. I wanted to try using DFS to solve it as well because DFS is supposedly easier to implement than BFS, but using DFS gives me the wrong answer.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<pair<int, int>> adj[50001];
bool visited[50001] = {0};
int maxdist = -1, maxnode = -1;

void dfs(int node, int d)
{
    visited[node] = 1;
    if (d > maxdist)
    {
        maxdist = d;
        maxnode = node;
    }
    for(auto u: adj[node])
    {
        if(!visited[u.first])
        {
            dfs(u.first, d+u.second);
        }

    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            int a, b, l;
            cin >> a >> b >> l;
            adj[a].push_back(make_pair(b, l));
            adj[b].push_back(make_pair(a, l));
        }

        dfs(1, 0);
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            visited[i] = 0;
        }
        dfs(maxnode, 0);

        cout << maxdist << endl;

    }

}
```

Comment: Get rid of the global variables.  That `dfs` function should be self-contained, without reliance on outside variables.  Also, you really should not simply post verbatim what you give to SPOJ or any other online judge website.  Formulate your code so that 1) It is compilable on any compiler, 2) Get rid of the "test case" loop and simply assign the test data directly into the program.  For 1), get rid of the `bits` header and include the proper header files.  Also use `std::vector`, not some gigantic global array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will make it work, but you are sharing adj[] and visited[] between different test cases, make sure to clean them up before a new test case.